# Implementing a DNS server in Java with Dynamo DB as the backend data store

Tags: java, dns

We use Dynamo DB to store SRV and A records corresponding to the applications/services in our domain. We would implement a DNS server written in Java with Dynamo DB store as the backend, so that standard DNS client libraries should be able to interact with it. Is there a known DNS interface library in java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/)

> dnsjava is an implementation of DNS in Java. It supports all defined record types (including the DNSSEC types), and unknown types. It can be used for queries, zone transfers, and dynamic updates. It includes a cache which can be used by clients, and a minimal implementation of a server. It supports TSIG authenticated messages, partial DNSSEC verification, and EDNS0.